# Permutation for balls

Tags: permutations

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [number of combination in which no two red balls are adjacent.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/137577/number-of-combination-in-which-no-two-red-balls-are-adjacent)

> We have $N$ slots. They have to be filled with balls (either green or red), one ball for each slot. Green balls can not be placed in consecutive slots. Find the number of different arrangements.

Can some one help?

Comment: I have answered the question today on this site, for white and red, with no two red in a row.

Comment: Can you plz share the link..?

Comment: [Here it is](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/137577/number-of-combination-in-which-no-two-red-balls-are-adjacent)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might have been useful, and not difficult, to find the number of possibilities for $N=1$, $N=2$, $N=3$, and perhaps $N=4$.

So that the question will not be listed as unanswered, [here is the link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/137577/number-of-combination-in-which-no-two-red-balls-are-adjacent) to a solution of an essentially identical question.