# what is the formula to calculate the permutations

Tags: permutations

I am new to the permutations. I have a problem with me for which I am not able to use proper formula -

**Problem:**
There are X boxes in which balls need to be placed. The balls are of two colors - BLUE RED. We have unlimited balls of both colors. We need to find the number of permutations / ways in which the balls will be placed in the boxes in such a way that BLUE balls never come together.

**Solution**
So far I have reached to the below formula-
= (Total number of arrangements - Arrangements of BLUE balls sitting together)
= (2^X - Arrangements of BLUE balls sitting together)

I am stuck for **Arrangements of BLUE balls sitting together**

What should be the right formula for this ?

Comment: what does mean BLUE balls never come together?i think it means that in each ball there is 1  blue only right?

Comment: sorry in each box i meant

Comment: each box can contain only 1 ball. BLUE balls never come together means no two adjacent boxes can contain blue balls.

Comment: This question has been recently asked and [answered](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/137577/number-of-combination-in-which-no-two-red-balls-are-adjacent) on MSE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denote by $b(n)$ the number of arrangements on $n$ boxes such that at least two blue balls are neighbours (I'll call this a "bad" arrangement).
I'm going for a [recurrence relation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation).

Assume that we know $b(k)$ for $k < n$.
Now consider the first box. If it contains a red ball, we have $b(n-1)$  combinations which complete this to a bad arrangement. If it contains a blue ball and the second box also contains a blue ball, the arrangement is bad no matter what the other boxes contain, so we have $2^{n-2}$ arrangements in this case. If the second box contains a red ball, we have $b(n-2)$ combinations which yield a bad arrangement.

So $b(n) = b(n-1) + b(n-2) + 2^{n-2}$. The initial values are
$b(1) = 0$ and $b(2) = 1$.
You should be able to find a closed form expression using methods described e.g. [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving_non-homogeneous_recurrence_relations), but right now I don't have the time to do it myself.  ;)

Comment: thanks @m_l this resolved my problem