# How many numbers from $1$ to $2^n$ will have $``11"$ as substring in binary representation?

Tags: combinatorics, binary

For example say, $n = 2$. So our set is $\{1, 2, 3, 4\}$ in base $10$ and  $\{1, 10, 11, 100\}$ in base $2$. So Output $1$, because only one number i.e. $3$ is there such that it has $``11"$ in it.

For $n = 3$, we get $\{3, 6, 7\}$ as having $``11"$, so output $3$.

Comment: The binary representation will have at least $1$ and at most $n+1$ digits, the latter one being $2^n$. So count the appearances of $11$ in strings with length $\in \{2,...n\}$.

Comment: That will be so much computation.

Comment: Not really: for strings of $k$ digits there are $(k-1)!2^{k-2}$ for which $11$ appears at least once.

Comment: @Uzman: That formula is incorrect. For $k=3$ it gives $4$, but the correct number is $3$.

Comment: Oh yes, my formula overcounts. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$2^n$ does not. All of the other integers in the given range can be written as $n$-bit strings, with leading zeroes as needed. Thus, you want the number of $n$-bit strings that have two adjacent ones. It’s actually easier to count those that do *not* have two adjacent ones and subtract from $2^n$. That problem is solved in [this question and answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/137577/number-of-combination-in-which-no-two-red-balls-are-adjacent): there are $F_{n+2}$ such sequences, where $F_n$ is the $n$-th [Fibonacci number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number). The number that you want is therefore $2^n-F_{n+2}$.

The Fibonacci numbers are defined recursively, but the linked article gives closed forms. Perhaps the most convenient for computation is

$$F_n=\left\lfloor\frac{\varphi^n}{\sqrt5}+\frac12\right\rfloor\;,$$

where $$\varphi=\frac{1+\sqrt5}2\;.$$

Comment: Thank you! (Characters limit... :p)

Comment: @user123: You’re welcome!